# How do I save a value in an external variable?

Tags: python, date, datetime, tkinter, tkcalendar

The doubt was the following, I want to select a date using the `tkcalendar` library, it is selected correctly, but I cannot use the variable outside the function.

```
def dateentry_view():
    def print_sel():
        date = cal.get_date()
        print(date)
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    ttk.Label(top, text='Elige el día').pack()
    cal = DateEntry(top)
    cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    ttk.Button(top, text="Aceptar", command=print_sel).pack()
```

How can I pass the `date` variable to display it in a `Label` as follows:

```
labelDate = Label(root,textvariable=date)
```

I have tried to put the `Label` inside the function, but it still doesn't show the `date` variable.

```
def dateentry_view():
    
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    ttk.Label(top, text='Elige el día').pack()
    cal = DateEntry(top)
    cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    ttk.Button(top, text="Aceptar", command=print_sel).pack() 

    def print_sel():
         date = cal.get_date()
         print(date)
         labelFecha = Label(root,textvariable=date)
```

When I print `date` it shows me the date I have selected correctly.

Comment: Read about Python keywords `global` and `nonlocal`.

Comment: `global/nonlocal` is not needed here!  Any time you're using those keywords you're *probably* setting yourself up for pain.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Never knew that there was a `nonlocal` keyword. Mind giving a bit of explanation?

Comment: @TheLizzard: You can read about it in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From googling `tk.Label` it looks like the idea of `textvariable` is that it refers to a mutable `tk.StringVar`, not a normal Python `str` (which is immutable).  Hence all you need to do is declare the `StringVar` in the outer scope and then update it inside the callback:

```
    date = tk.StringVar()
    def set_date():
         date.set(cal.get_date())

    ttk.Button(top, text="Aceptar", command=set_date).pack() 
    labelFecha = Label(root, textvariable=date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the `textvariable-` option properly. You need to set it a reference to an instance of a [`tk.StringVar`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201031100214id_/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) variable class. Afterwards any changes to the variable's value will automatically update what the widget displays.

Also note that the `tkcalendar.DateEntry.get_date()` method returns a `datetime.date`, not a string, so you'll need manual to convert it into one yourself before setting the `StringVar`'s value to it.

Here's a runnable example illustrating what I am saying:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry


def dateentry_view():
    def print_sel():
        date = cal.get_date()  # Get datetime.date.
        fechaStr = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  # Convert datetime.date to string.
        fechaVar.set(fechaStr)  # Update StringVar with formatted date.
        top.destroy()  # Done.

    top = tk.Toplevel(root)

    ttk.Label(top, text='Elige el día').pack()
    cal = DateEntry(top)
    cal.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    ttk.Button(top, text="Aceptar", command=print_sel).pack()


root = tk.Tk()

ttk.Button(root, text="Ejecutar prueba", command=dateentry_view).pack()
fechaVar = tk.StringVar(value='<no date>')  # Create and initialize control variable.
labelFecha = tk.Label(root, textvariable=fechaVar)  # Use it.
labelFecha.pack()

root.mainloop()
```